# css animation from current position(unknown) to bottom: 0%

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an image sticking out of the bottom of the screen. I want to slide up the image using a CSS animation.

The problem is the image dimensions vary depending on the size of the window. Thus I do not know initially how much of the image is sticking out of the screen.

Simply what I want to do is move the image to bottom: 0%

So the code would look similar to this except that I don't know the starting percentage (I don't know it's -35%).

```
@-moz-keyframes moveUpImage
{
    0% { bottom: -35% }
    100% { bottom: 0% }
}
```

Is there a way to tell CSS that I want the animation to go from starting/current position to bottom: 0% ?

Comment: css transition/animation relies on your input start/end values to calculate the **interpolation**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a css animation from the current position of the element to the bottom use css transitions, doing it that way you just need to apply the bottom position and the animation will take place. (probably using position absolute).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried what you suggested but it seems like with css transitions I still need to provide the original/current value of bottom. If I don't then there's no animation and the element just changes it's position instantly.